# Bootstrap Popup - Attach event to button for popover dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I intend to use the Bootstrap Popover module as a confirmation for a delete event, such that when a `<button>` is clicked, instead of simply firing a function it opens a popup which let's the user **confirm** or **dismiss** the action.

*It should be noted for context that the environment is a self-built, one-page ~mvc webapp, where the elements are added dynamically (I thus do not know the number of elements beforehand, nor can I hardcode the actions for each element)*

---

In the current situation (without the popover) I do something similar to this to trigger the direct (non-conformation) action:

```
$view.on('click', '.deleteButton', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    api.delete('someUrl' + id, successFunction);
}):
```

Where the button would have a markup similar to this:

```
<button class="deleteButton" data-id="2">Delete me!</button>
```

---

However, now I wish to add a confirmation step (e.g. "Are you sure you want to delete this magnificent button? (Y/N)"), and thought of using bootstrap popover.

After brainstorming a bit, what I came up with was a strategy like the following. It is not the optimal solution (the optimal solution would be to extend the popover module so that I would be able to pass in confirmationFunction and cancelFunction to the popover).

Firstly, I would have to initiate the popovers.

```
$view.find('.deleteButton').popover({
  title: 'Are you sure?', //Example title
  html: true, //Essential for the html to work as expected
  selector: '.deleteButton', //Allow ajaxing in of new elements
  container: '.viewName', //So that the popovers reside w/in the current view and thus can be bound to $view (a jQuery object for the view)
  content: [...], //Two <button>s with a specified class, e.g. .viewName__deleteButton--popover
});
```

Secondly, I would bind an event to the buttons inside the popover

```
$view.on('click', '.viewName__deleteButton--popover', function () {
    var id = ??; // Here comes the troubling part - how do I get the ID of the clicked button? How can I target the original button? If I can do that, I think it would solve everything.
    api.delete('someUrl' + id, successFunction);
});
```

The problem that arises is *how do I target the originally clicked button?*

The only soultion which I can come up with, which isn't very neat at all is to do something like this:

```
var popoverId = $(this).parents('.popover').attr('id'); //returns popoverXXXXXX
var parentElement = $view.find('[aria-describedBy="' + popoverId + '"]');
```

It works, but it is a very dirty solution and does not feel 'nice' att all.

Is there any way this can be done in a neater manner? Preferably I would be able to define a general function such as `$element.confirmationPopover({popoverSettings...}, confirmationFunction, declineFunction);` which could be used in multiple cases.

(PS: I couldn't figure out a concise title for this Q, advice is as always appreciated!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating an extension to jQuery, such that:

```
$.fn.confirmationPopover = function (passedInOptions) {
  var $view = this;

  var defaultOptions = {
    confirmationLabel: 'Yes',
    container: '.' + this.attr('class'),
    declineLabel: 'No',
    html: true,
    placement: 'left',  //top | left | right | bottom
    rowClasses: false
  };

  if (!passedInOptions.declineClass) {
    passedInOptions.declineClass = passedInOptions.selector + '__popover__decline';
  }

  var obj = {}; //Merged options
  $.extend(true, obj, defaultOptions, passedInOptions);

  var popoverContent = '<div class="row ' + (obj.rowClasses ? obj.rowClasses : 'tac') + '">' +
                        '<button class="button button--small ' + obj.confirmationClass + '">' + obj.confirmationLabel + '</button>' +
                        '<button class="button button--small button--outline ' + obj.declineClass + '">' + obj.declineLabel + '</button>' +
                      '</div>';

  if (!obj.content) {
    obj.content = popoverContent;
  }

  /* Initiate Popover */
  $view.popover(obj);

  /**
   * Bind confirmation Button
   */
  $view.on('click', '.' + obj.confirmationClass, function () {
    var popoverId = $(this).parents('.popover').attr('id');
    var $this = $view.find('[aria-describedBy="' + popoverId + '"]');
    obj.confirmationFunction($this);
  });

  /**
   * Bind decline button
   */
  $view.on('click', '.' + obj.declineClass, function () {
    var popoverId = $(this).parents('.popover').attr('id');
    var $this = $view.find('[aria-describedBy="' + popoverId + '"]');
    if (typeof obj.declineFunction === 'function') {
      obj.declineFunction($this);
    } else {
      $this.popover('hide');
    }
  });

  return this;
};
```

Comment: Thanks @j-santosh, but I'm afraid I have to wait 18 hours before I can do so :)

Comment: oh , i don't know that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [popoverX](http://plugins.krajee.com/popover-x/demo)! . It's slightly modal-ish version of bootstrap popovers.